# Declaração de FUNÇÃO dentro de FUNÇÃO em Python

Tags: python-3.x, funções

Estou tentando declarar um função que mostra uma linha abaixo do resultado de uma outra função. Essa linha se adapta ao tamanho do resultado retornado na função 'principal'.
Segue o código e a mensagem de erro que está aparecendo:

```
from time import sleep

def mostraLinha(tamLinha):
  print('=' * tamLinha)
  print()

def maior(* n):
  print('PROCESSANDO...', flush=True)
  sleep(1.5)
  for num in n:
    sleep(0.6)
    print(f'{num}', end = ' > ', flush=True)
    if num == n[0]:
      maior = num
    else:
      if num > maior:
        maior = num
  print()
  print(f'Foram analisados {len(n)} números e o maior é o {maior}.')
  parâmetro = len(n)
  mostraLinha(parâmetro)


def mostraLinha():
  print('=' * 25)
  print()


print('Desempacotando PARÂMETROS')
print('-' * 30)
print()
maior(-5, 14, 102, 3, 5)
maior(3, 5)
maior(1056, 100456, 0, -345, 6, 7, 8, 15, 21)
```

**MENSAGEM DE ERRO:**

> `MOSTRALINHA()` TAKES 0 POSITIONAL ARGUMENTS BUT 1 WAS GIVEN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem duas funções com o mesmo nome:

```
def mostraLinha(tamLinha):
  print('=' * tamLinha)
  print()
```

e:

```
def mostraLinha():
  print('=' * 25)
  print()
```

Aqui você passa um parametro: `mostraLinha(parâmetro)`, as a função executa a segunda e me parece que você deseja executar a primeira, creio que a segunda nem deveria existir.

Comment: Perfeito Guilherme. Acho que eu enviei errado a mensagem, acredita? Não estava no bloco de código essa segunda função! Detalhes fazem a diferença hehe

Comment: @dev.curi se resolveu o problema marque a resposta como correta, obrigado

Comment: Feito amigo! Pegando a manha...

Comment: @dev.curi obrigado o/